# How to fit a surface to a set of points (x,y,z)?

Tags: calculus, math-software

I have some data which I would like to fit a surface to. More specifically, I am conducting a project on hydrology investigating velocity and flow rate. I collected data from a stream and would like to know I can could fit a surface to it.
To find discharge, we multiply velocity by the area that the water is crossing. However, in a stream, the velocity is constantly changing. Therefore, the following formula gives us the total discharge $Q$:
$$Q=\iint\limits_Rv(x,y)\,dA$$
where $v(x,y)$ is the velocity at the point $(x,y)$ and the region $R$ is the area of water we are integrating over. On the x-axis, I would have the depth of the water, and on the y-axis, the distance from the bank. This integral would then give us the total discharge.
Do you know of any free software that fits a surface to 3D data?

Thank you.

Comment: Please could you clarify a little. It seems you have a set of data points $(x_1, y_1, v_1)$, $(x_2, y_2, v_2)$, $\ldots$, $(x_N, y_N, v_N)$. Are you seeking a function $f$ to model these data? I.e. some $f$ such that $f(x_i,y_i) = v_i$ (interpolation) or $f(x_i,y_i) \approx v_i$ (approximation)? Also, are your sample locations $(x_1, y_1)$, $\ldots$, $(x_N,y_N)$ arranged on a regular lattice, or are they arranged irregularly?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for some sort of interpolation function. My samples location are arranged on a regular lattice.

Comment: Python is free and has a [library that can carry out this kind of interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html). This would involve writing some code.